# how to get my site name from different database table (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, admin

I have 3 database table, Sites, Admins, Peoples
A people logged in, and he/she wanted to manage the sites that he/she have admins right.
How can I show all the site name that he/she has? How to pass in the variable?

Heres my code:

**AccountController:**

```
public function getManage(){
    return View::make('account.settings.manage')
        ->with('admins', Admin::where('people_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get());
}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/account/setting/manage', array(
        'as' => 'account-setting-manage',
        'uses' => 'AccountController@getManage'
    ));
```

**View:**

```
<ul>
    @foreach($admins as $admin)
    <li><a href="">{{ $admin->site_id }} </a></li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

**SQL:**

Everytime a site is created, people_id(user) and site_id will be stored in admins table

```
create table admins(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    people_id int,
    site_id int,
    created_at datetime,
    updated_at datetime,
    primary key(id)
);
```

Comment: Do you have a relationship setup? How does your system know which sites admins can manage?

Comment: **SQL:**

Everytime a site is created, people_id(user) and site_id will be stored in admins table

    create table admins(
     id int not null auto_increment,
     people_id int,
     site_id int,
     created_at datetime,
     updated_at datetime,
     primary key(id)
    );